# NoSuchMethodError while using aar library

Tags: android, compilation, aar

I am using third party aar library in my project and it cryshes while trying to call android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(IIII)V.

I included latest version of support library in my gradle file, I even checked apk file and there is SwipeRefreshLayout that has setColorScheme method.

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme
        at com.someaarlib.AARActivity.init(AARActivity.java:87)
        at com.someaarlib.AARActivity.onCreate(AARActivity.java:71)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What can cause that exception?

UPDATE
I've tried to use method SwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme in my app and it works fine I suppose problem is in the aar library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in aar library. Apparently authors mixed up with dependencies while compiling aar library.